# IIS & NGINX DDOS Protection

Tags: nginx, security, iis, proxy, ddos

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server with IIS currently set up on it and I was wondering what my options were to make this DDOS Protected. I've seen Remote DDOS Protection available from various sites but I'm not sure if it's what I want.

I also have another Linux server which I can install any distro on if that can be used as the proxy. I'm just looking to hide the Windows server's IP and the proxy masking the real IP to not be able to be hit off easily. Can anyone help suggest my options?

I've been suggested to use NGINX on my linux server and configure that as a reverse proxy to point to my windows server. Can NGINX have effective ddos protection?

Thanks.

Comment: Although you may be able to tune a reverse proxy to for instance cache content relieving the burden on the backend server almost by definition you can’t mitigate a DDoS attack at the end point (or with a single server)

Comment: I forgot to reply to this thread, but I successfully set NGINX up and it managed to withstand upwards of 60,000 bots at once, and stopped 300,000 bots after just a few seconds by banning the IP's and rate limiting. It is definitely possible :)